# Dynamically setting text in JTextField in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, settext

I am creating an account creation tool for my software.  In this tool, it asks you for your name, email address, etc., and I use JTextFields to collect this information.

I wanted to try something different and have invalid information fixed in real time.  I have my code set up so that whenever a the text field has changed, a method is run to remove unwanted characters and do some other things.  The code sort of looks like this:

```
private void firstNameUpdate(){
    String name = firstNameField.getText();
    int pos = firstNameField.getCaretPosition();
    if (!name.equals("")){
        name = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase();
        if (!name.equals("")){
            name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
            validFirstName = true;
        } else {
            validFirstName = false;
        }
    } else {
        validFirstName = false;
    }
    firstNameField.setText(name);
    firstNameField.setCaretPosition(pos);
}
```

The code, 'firstNameField.setText(name);' is what causes the error.  I know everything else in the method works because I tried having it print out to the console instead.

All sources that I have seen say that this should work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be using a `DocumentFilter`, but what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For real-time filteration of text components, you should be using a `DocumentFilter`.

Take a look at [Implementing a `DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [these examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter).

The likely cause is you are getting a concurrent modification error, where you are trying to modify the underlying fields document while it is been modified.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!